# How to show selected option of mat-select in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here my mat-select dropdown in this dropdown i have multiple users when i select any user i want to show this selected username but in ngModel i have userObject.userid that i dont want to change how it is possible to show name of any selected user.

chat.component.html

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 25%;margin-top: 20px;margin-left: 20px;">
  <mat-select placeholder="Select User" [(ngModel)]="userObject.userid" name="userid" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of userObj" [value]="item.userid">
      {{item.username}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>  

<h2>Selected : {{userObject.username}}</h2>
```

Comment: the first question is: do you need to store the selected name in your `userObject` member or simply display it in the template?

Comment: yes i want to show and also want to store in userObject

Comment: but using ngModel i store it userid and i want to display username

Comment: Added an answer

Answer (score 1):

I would just bind the whole object to the select, and use a variable for example called `selectedUser`. Apparently you need the `userid`, but it is safely stored in the variable, as well as the `username`. So what I would do... (also change some variable names to distinguish them):

```
<mat-select placeholder="Select User" [(ngModel)]="selectedUser" name="userid" required>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let userObj of users" [value]="userObj">
    {{userObj.username}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>

{{selectedUser.userid}}, {{selectedUser.username}}
```